# How can i make this image resizer fast?

Tags: java, performance

Here is the current ImageResizer class I have.

It currently takes about 0.4 seconds per image, which is very slow, when you have to process 100k images.

Please let me know how I can make this faster using java.
(please excuse the very dirty code, i been shuffling it around a lot, and never got a chance to clean it up)

```
package helpers;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class ImageResizer {
public static final int VERTICAL = 0;
public static final int HORIZONTAL = 1;

public static final String IMAGE_JPEG = "jpeg";
public static final String IMAGE_JPG = "jpg";
public static final String IMAGE_PNG = "png";

public static InputStream resizeImage(byte[] image, int maxWidth) {

    InputStream inputStream = null;

    Image img = (new ImageIcon(image)).getImage();
    ImageIcon picture = scaleImage(img, maxWidth, HORIZONTAL);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    saveToStream(picture, out, IMAGE_JPEG);

    inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

    return inputStream;
}

public static InputStream getThumbnail(byte[] image) {
    return resizeImage(image, 100);
}

private static ImageIcon scaleImage(Image image, int size, int dir) {
    if (dir == HORIZONTAL) {
        return new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(size, -1, Image.SCALE_FAST));
    } else {
        return new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(-1, size, Image.SCALE_FAST));
    }
}

private static void saveToStream(ImageIcon picture, OutputStream file, String imageType) {
    if (picture != null) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(picture.getIconWidth(), picture.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(picture.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(bi, imageType, file);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Resized image could not be saved");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have you determined what takes so long? Is it disk I/O or CPU?

Comment: it is image.getScaledInstance(), i assume CPU, it doesnt get maxxed out though. Disk I/O shouldn't be the case, my development machine has a 6GB/s SSD, and I am doing everything in memory.

Answer (score 1):

This article: [Perils of Image.getScaledInstance](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) recommends the scaling variant of Graphics.drawImage().

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some freedom on the sizes? Then use images of size of power of two, and\or use a scaling ratio which is a multiple of two (at least an integer). This is a generic algorithmic advice, as I am not familiar with Java image library.